# Deploy Python/Flask on a robust web server on windows

Tags: windows, web-services, flask, python-3.4

I have a windows machine which is running Python 3.4 with Flask.

But of course the Flask development server is slow and sometimes I need to host my applications locally for local usage so I need to host it on a more robust web server on windows.

How to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got it. used [This Guide Here](https://csparpa.github.io/blog/2013/03/how-to-deploy-flask-applications-to-apache-webserver.html) to setup apache with mod_wsgi.